# How to best approach ANOVA with multiple response variables that might be correlated and Bonferroni Correction

Tags: r, anova, multiple-comparisons, manova, bonferroni

I need some help verifying a simple analysis.  I have completed a simple two factor experiment of more or less equal sample sizes.  Let's assume for the case of this question that the sample sizes are equal.  In each factor, there are two treatments thus there are 4 total treatments.  I have measured four response variables.  However, the four response variables show high correlation in pairs.  That is response variables 1 and 2 are highly correlated with each other and response variables 3 and 4 are highly correlated with each other.  Looking at the correlation of response variable {1,3}, {1,4}, and so on shows low correlation.  That is because the first response variable will be a length of a branch and the second response variable is the number of leaves on the same branch and the same pattern follows for response variables 3 and 4.

I want to do two tests. I want to look at the two factors and interaction effects on each response variable and I want to do two MANOVA's on the two pairs of response variables.  My questions are as follows:

1) Do I have to do a Bonferonni correction to control for Type 1 error here?  My feeling is that I do.  Because I am doing two MANOVA tests and four ANOVA tests, I will have an increased likelihood of making a type 1 error.  However, I'm not sure if my number of tests is 6 or 2 and 4 respectively (are the MANOVA tests different/separate from the ANOVA tests?).

2) I would first look at the MANOVA test results for what are the main effects and then afterwards do the individual ANOVA tests right?  By doing the MANOVA first, I can see what effects have on the pairs and then the individual ANOVA tests can show which specific response variables contribute to the pair effects?

I have a hard time keeping all of the assumptions in line when doing these sort of things.  Additionally, my ANOVA class never covered MANOVA / multiple response variables for the same experiment.  Thanks for your help and please let me know if there is any more information I can provide to help.

Comment: You should definitely **be careful** about multiple testing, but it is indeed difficult to say what the "effective" number of tests here is. If dependent variables (DVs) 1 and 2 are highly correlated, then obviously these two ANOVAs will not be independent. The same is true for the two ANOVAs on DVs 3 and 4. Finally, each MANOVA is definitely not independent from the respective ANOVAs. The strength of the Bonferroni correction is that it makes no assumptions: if your p-values are still significant after Bonferroni, good for you. (Cont.)

Comment: But its weakness is that it is very strict, and if the tests are in fact dependent you will loose a lot of power (imagine doing ANOVAs on almost-identical DVs 1 and 2, and both come out with $p=0.03$ which you would be happy to call significant; multiplying it by two is essentially a waste, since you effectively measured the same p-value twice, so it's not "really" a multiple testing). One possible strategy would be to run two MANOVAs with Bonferroni first, and proceed to ANOVAs (without any additional Bonferroni) only if respective MANOVAs report significant effects.

Comment: Thank you for replying amoeba! I will explore your suggestion of looking at MANOVAs with Bonferroni and then proceeding to ANOVAs.  I have submitted this inquiry to a statistical consultant at my school.  I will write a comment with their input as well for future users of CV with a similar question.

Comment: Cool, looking forward to hearing what the consultant is going to say (note that you can provide an answer to your own question, and then either accept it or leave un-accepted if you hope for a better answer). This might spark further discussion here.